# Pick up a date with native codeigniter instead of HTML

Tags: codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter and the MVC architecture to build a form on ExpressionEngine.

My problem is that CodeIgniter doesn't have the input date that I can use with HTML. My code is something like:

```
$data['cycle_begin'] = form_input('cycle_begin');

$data['cycle_month'] = form_input('cycle_month');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    ee()->db->insert('exp_credit_tracker_assoc',
                array(
                    'cycle_begin' => $_POST['cycle_begin'],
                    'cycle_months' => $_POST['cycle_month']
                )
            );
}
```

The view is something in the line of:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="cycle_type">cycle_type</label><?= $cycle_type ?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="cycle_begin">cycle_begin</label><?= $cycle_begin ?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="cycle_month">cycle_month</label><?= $cycle_month ?>
</div>
```

Is there any form_date which I could use or my only option is to change the input in my view file and grab the value in some way in my control file?

Comment: there is not date type of input in form helper in CI , you must  modified it in controller or in view with the help of date helper or native php

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/date_helper.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no any `form_date` input type which you could use.

you can do some thing like this :

```
$data['cycle_begin'] = form_input('date_name',['type' =>'date']);
```

You can modify `form_input` as date input like this

```
<?php
$data = array(
        'name'          => 'mydate',
        'id'            => 'mydate',
        'value'         => '03-04-2012',
        'type'          => 'date',
        'format'        =>'m-d-Y'
);

echo form_input($data); 
?>
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Comment: I did something similar, but I don't love the idea of mixing code: $data['cycle_begin'] = "<input name='date' type='date'>";

Comment: do just like this : $data['cycle_begin'] = form_input('date_name',['type' =>'date']);

Comment: please, post it, so I can mark it as the best solution